# How to redirect my Custom URl to specific Port in ASP.Net IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, .net, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

i have created two sites, one is on Port 80 which is default site and other is on port 786, now i want that if the user opens url http://myurl.com/Application, it should open http://myurl.com:786/Application. I have installed IIS 7.5 Rewrite module. I tried code with different ways, forexample

```
<rule name="Red" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.myurl.com/Application" />

             </conditions>

        <action type="Rewrite" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}:786/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it likes a 301 permanent redirect. 
You can use HttpModule to do this.

```
public class CustomHttpModule : IHttpModule
{

    private HttpApplication app;

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        app = context;
        app.AuthorizeRequest += App_AuthorizeRequest;
    }

    public void App_AuthorizeRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpRequest req = app.Request;
        string path = req.Path;

        // if starts with http://{HTTP_HOST}
        if (path.StartsWith("http://{HTTP_HOST}", true, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
        {
            string redirectUrl = path.Replace("http://{HTTP_HOST}", "http://{HTTP_HOST}:786");
            app.Response.StatusCode = 301;
            app.Response.AddHeader("Location", redirectUrl);
            app.Response.End();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

Also, you need to config this HttpModule in system.webserver node and system.web node.

Answer (score 0):

```
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/Application$" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
```

this can only resolve the issue.